# GPIO в UART на Arduino

Tags: uart, arduino-uno, gpio

Возможно ли перепрограмировать GPIO pins в UART pins?
На мой платине есть только 1 пара Serial pins и мне не хватает

Comment: Если используете Arduino IDE, можно использовать класс [SoftwareSerial](https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/built-in-libraries/software-serial), он позволяет использовать нестандартные пины.

Comment: Супер, спасибо)